# Carbon Specialized Sirrus X5.0 Help

Tags: frames, carbon

I am very new to this thread and seeking help from an experienced bike enthusiast. I just purchased the aforementioned bike in the title and after bringing it home for inspection (bought brand new from a shop mid-NYC which currently doesn’t allow entry) I noticed a scratch/marking behind the seat post. I was advised to take the seat post out to inspect the inner area to see if it’s structural damage. I will post pics below. My question; is this going to bite me in the behind later down the road or should I take it back? No bike shops had this anywhere so I had to drive an hour plus each way to find it. Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a mere scratch, no crack shows on the inner surface. Did you forward the photos to the shop?

Comment: Yes I did and no reply. The shop is in nyc as I couldn’t find this bike anywhere. I brought it to two of my local shops one being a specialized dealer who inspected the bike closely and determined (without an X-ray ) it’s just a surface clear coat crack not compromising the frame. They told me to mark the bottom part with a sharpie and measure the length to see if it grows. Others speculate that some shops haven’t even received this bike this year yet due to covid and it being a poor production / qc job. I would have inspected it at the specialized store in nyc but they don’t allow entry

Comment: I would take it back, if you zoom in on the image you can clearly see lots of what looks like scuff marks, I would not expect this on a new bike. It's only my opinion but it looks like it's had maybe a saddle bag rubbing on the frame.

Comment: Yeah, I hope I can do it from a local specialized shop, what a nightmare all I want to do is enjoy and I have to deal with scratch scuffed whatever bs. I will contact my local specialized shop and see if somethings possible through them. If I have to go back to the city to deal with that nonsense on 7th ave I will be a super unpleasant individual.  Thanks for your opinion. My local shop stated they haven’t even revived these yet and who knows how long to get a new frame